# make intermediate variable available in next calling function

Tags: r, scope

This is some sample code:

```
a<-c(1,2); 
f1<-function(dataset){
        cat("a=",a,"\n");
        b<-rev(a);
        cat("b=",b,"\n");
        f2("b");}
f2<-function(dataset){ 
        print(exists(dataset));
        print(dataset); # do analysis on dataset b
}
```

Output:

```
> f1(a)
a= 1 2 
b= 2 1 
[1] FALSE
[1] "b"
```

How do I make the intermediate variable b be available in function f2 (without changing function f2 which belongs to some package)?

Thanks.

Comment: why not `f2(b)`? Can you explain how b needs to be available in `f2`?

Comment: @JakeBurkhead f2 is the `comproc` function in a package (see below comments). not sure why not f2(b) as I didn't write that package.

Answer (score 0):

I do get

```
> f1(a)
a= 1 2 
b= 2 1 
[1] TRUE
[1] "b"
```

however in this situations I use the `envir` paramenter of `exists` ( even if belong to some package you can still change it)

```
f2<-function(dataset){ 
  print(exists(dataset, envir=envir=parent.frame()))
  print(dataset) # do analysis on dataset b
}
```

If you really cannot modify `f2` you have to "improve" `f1`...

```
a<-c(1,2)
f1<-function(dataset){
  f2<-function(dataset){ 
    print(exists(dataset, envir=parent.frame()))
    print(dataset) # do analysis on dataset b
  }
  cat("a=",a,"\n")
  b<-rev(a)
  cat("b=",b,"\n")
  f2("b")
}

> f1(a)
a= 1 2 
b= 2 1 
[1] TRUE
[1] "b"
```

the issue is, `R` looks for objects named "b" in the current environment (which the function `b` itself) then, if no object `b` is found, goes into the "upper" level...

this upper level is the parent environment inside which `b` is defined ( in your case the `.GlobalEnv`), and `b` is not there but inside `f1`.

Defining `f2` inside `f1` makes `R` going to look for `b` in `f1` before going into the `.GlabalEnv`. My first solution made use of `parent.frame`, which explicitly asks`R` to look for the object into the environment where `f2` was invoked, which is a different concept than parent environment.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without editing f2 which exists in some package? make b available in scope of f2.

Comment: @user2540309 yes and no... the only way would be defining `f2` inside `f1`. see the edit

Comment: @user2540309 It really sounds like you're trying to do something that you shouldn't be doing.  Maybe you could explain your actual situation?  It's possible you're trying to find a solution to a problem that shouldn't exist because you're going about it the wrong way?

Comment: @user2540309 you may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439110/what-is-the-difference-between-parent-frame-and-parent-env-in-r-how-do-they) as well

Comment: the situation is function f2 exists in a package which I would prefer to leave untouched. f1 is just a wrapper to do a transformation on the data before passing it to f2 to crunch. I know one way is use b<<-rev(a) but this leaves b in the global environment at the end so I was wondering if there are alternatives...

Comment: Now it sounds more like `f2` is doing something it shouldn't be doing. Can you post the actual code of `f2`? It shouldn't need to use anything like `exists`.

Comment: function f2 is the comproc function from the roc suite: http://labs.fhcrc.org/pepe/dabs/rocbasic.html. E.g. `comproc(dataset="nnhs2", d="d", markers=c("y1","y2"))`, inside comproc, it checks `if(exists(dataset))`. I didn't write the code but it seems legitimate to me. All I want to do is call comproc within my function that sets up a transform version of dataset as the simple example shows. any suggestions?

Comment: @user2540309 I tried to simulate `f2` being in a package defining it in a `new.env` and assigning `b` in that environment (in your case you can assign `b` inside the package of `comproc`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have variable "b" in function2, however it doesn't exist in the global space.

"exist("b")" show FALSE, but in the region of f2, b has the value and can be worked on.

```
a<-c(1,2);
f2<-function(dataset){ 
        print(dataset); # do analysis on dataset b
        return(dataset+1)
}

f1<-function(dataset){
        cat("a=",a,"\n");
        b<-rev(a);
        cat("b=",b,"\n");
        c <- f2(b);
        cat("c=",c,"\n");  
      }

f1(a)
```