# Nested function environment selection

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

I am writing some functions for doing repeated tasks, but I am trying to minimize the amount of times I load the data. Basically I have one function that takes some information and makes a plot. Then I have a second function that will loop through and output multiple plots to a .pdf. In both functions I have the following line of code:

```
if(load.dat) load("myworkspace.RData")
```

where `load.dat` is a logical and the data I need is stored in myworkspace.RData. When I am calling the wrapper function that loops through and outputs multiple plots I do not want to reload the workspace in every call to the inner function. I thought I could just load the workspace once in the wrapper function, then the inner function could access that data, but I got an error stating otherwise.

So my understanding was when a function cannot find the variable in its local environment (created when the function gets called), the function will look to the parent environment for the variable.

I assumed the parent environment to the inner function call would be the outer function call. Obviously this is not true:

```
func1 <- function(...){
  print(var1)
}

func2 <- function(...){
  var1 <- "hello"
  func1(...)
}

> func2()
Error in print(var1) : object 'var1' not found
```

After reading numerous questions, the language manual, and [this](http://digitheadslabnotebook.blogspot.com/2011/06/environments-in-r.html) really helpful blog post, I came up with the following:

```
var1 <- "hello"
save(list="var1",file="test.RData")
rm(var1)

func3 <- function(...){
  attach("test.RData")
  func1(...)
  detach("file:test.RData")
}

> func3()
[1] "hello"
```

Is there a better way to do this? Why doesn't `func1` look for undefined variables in the local environment created by `func2`, when it was `func2` that called `func1`?

Note: I did not know how to name this question. If anyone has better suggestions I will change it and edit this line out.

Comment: Lexical scoping means the function will look for undefined symbols in its parent environment, which is not necessarily the calling  environment. Check this also: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Environments

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Thanks for the link. I will work through that this afternoon.

Comment: If your data is in form of dataframes, you could use package `data.table`, and pass your tables as an argument to `func1` inside `func3`. This package works by reference and does not make unwanted copies of your data.

Comment: Not quite sure why it isn't seeing `var1`, but note that `print(parent.frame()$var1)` works fine.

Comment: @RichieCotton, `func1` looks for `var1` is its enclosing environment, i.e., where it belongs, which happens to be `R_GlobalEnv`. The call to `parent.frame()` inside `func1` inside `func3` returns the evaluation environment of `func3`, where `var1` belongs. (boy what a mess :-)

Comment: @dayne, I think you should be more specific in your question. How does your data look like?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft My data is two different data frames. I knew this question was kind of vague, but I am trying to better understand the environment definitions in r. Really I just do not understand why `func1` cannot see the environments created by `func2` or `func3`. Is there any way to get around this? Or to make functions look to other function environments?

Comment: @dayne, it is intentional that `func1` cannot see those environments. When you type `func1 <- function...` in the console, you are creating an object of type closure which has an environment property, equal to `R_GlobalEnv`. This is where R will look for symbols not resolved in the evaluation of `func1`'s body. The *evaluation* environment created during the execution of `func2` or `func3` is *irrelevant* WRT symbol lookup. A workaround is to use `parent.frame()$var1`, as Richie pointed above, but it is very ugly.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for your continued attention today!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To illustrate lexical scoping, consider the following:

First let's create a sandbox environment, only to avoid the oh-so-common R_GlobalEnv:

```
sandbox <-new.env()
```

Now we put two functions inside it: `f`, which looks for a variable named `x`; and `g`, which defines a local `x` and calls `f`:

```
sandbox$f <- function()
{
    value <- if(exists("x")) x else "not found."
    cat("This is function f looking for symbol x:", value, "\n")
}

sandbox$g <- function()
{
    x <- 123
    cat("This is function g. ")
    f()
}
```

Technicality: entering function definitions in the console causes then to have the enclosing environment set to `R_GlobalEnv`, so we manually force the enclosures of `f` and `g` to match the environment where they "belong":

```
environment(sandbox$f) <- sandbox
environment(sandbox$g) <- sandbox
```

Calling `g`. The local variable `x=123` is not found by `f`:

```
> sandbox$g()
This is function g. This is function f looking for symbol x: not found.
```

Now we create a `x` in the global environment and call `g`. The function `f` will look for `x` first in sandbox, and then in the parent of sandbox, which happens to be R_GlobalEnv:

```
> x <- 456
> sandbox$g()
This is function g. This is function f looking for symbol x: 456
```

Just to check that `f` looks for `x` first in its enclosure, we can put a `x` there and call `g`:

```
> sandbox$x <- 789
> sandbox$g()
This is function g. This is function f looking for symbol x: 789
```

Conclusion: symbol lookup in R follows the chain of enclosing environments, *not* the evaluation frames created during execution of nested function calls.

EDIT: Just adding a link to [this very interesting answer from Martin Morgan on the related subject of `parent.frame()` vs `parent.env()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439110/what-is-the-difference-between-parent-frame-and-parent-env-in-r-how-do-they/7439568#7439568)

Comment: This is the best illustration I have seen. Thank you so much! I was not really understanding the difference in environments and frames.

Answer (score 2):

You could use closures:

```
f2 <- function(...){
   f1 <- function(...){
     print(var1)
   }
   var1 <- "hello"
   f1(...)
 }
 f2()
```

Comment: Right, but I need to be able to use the inner function as a stand-alone function. I did not want to have to redefine the inner function every time I call the outer function (not to mention duplicate a bunch of code).

Comment: Then the cleanest setting in my opinion: put all your data in a list (my_data), then give it as argument to your function. Inside the function you may use with(my_data, { } ) to avoid extra typing.