# Why does <<- assignment work in my function, but <- doesn't?

Tags: r, assignment-operator

I am trying to understand the difference between `<-` and `<<-` in practice. I wrote the following function in `R` that relies on a couple of other small function that I wrote:

```
fun.exec <- function(x=dat){
  id1 <- prompt1()
  id2 <- prompt2()
  el.type <- data.switch(di=id1)
  dat.sifted <- data.sift(x, nc=id2)
  plots.list <- evol.tiles(ds=dat.sifted, dt=el.type, nc=id2)
  p <- evol.plot(l=plots.list, dt=el.type)
}
```

Functions `prompt1` and `prompt2` take an input from a user, `el.type()` assigns string name to the data (for use in describing different plots automatically), `data.sift()` extract relevant data from a big data frame object, `evol.tiles()` generates various ggplots to be organized in a grid, and `evol.plot()` puts the plots in a grid.

As can be seen, both `data.sift()` and `evol.tiles()` functions use the `id2` user's input. When I execute this function as is, I get an error:

```
Error in evol.tiles(ds = dat.sifted, dt = el.type, nc = id2) : object 
'id2' not found
```

If I replace `id2 <- prompt2()` with `id2 <<- prompt2()`, the code works as expected.

What I don't understand is why, as is, the code does not break on the `data.sift()` function, which also calls for `id2`. I read [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) for assignments, a couple of related posts on StackOverflow, and the [Scope](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#Scope) section from [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html) but I am still not sure what the problem is. It's almost as if after being used in `data.sift()` the variable was no longer available in the environment and I don't understand that is.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE:***
Here is the code for prompts:

```
prompt1 <- function(){
  cat('What do you want to create plots for? Your options are:
        1: data type A,
        2: data type B,
        3: data type C')
  readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
}

prompt2 <- function(){
  cat('How many nodes do you want to visualize?')
  n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
  cat('\nProvide coordinates of each node to visualize separated by commas.')
  l <- vector("list", n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    el <- readline(prompt=paste('Enter coordinnates for node',i,': '))
    l[[i]] <- el
  }
  return(l)
}
```

for `data.sift()`:

```
data.sift <- function(x, nc){
  nl <- lapply(nc, function(l){as.integer(unlist(strsplit(l,",")))})
  ds <- vector("list", length(nl))
  for (i in 1:length(nl)){
    ds[[i]] <- x[(x$x == nl[[i]][1] & x$y == nl[[i]][2] & x$z == nl[[i]][3]),]
  }
  return(ds)
}
```

and for `evol.tiles()`:

```
evol.tiles <- function(ds, dt, nc){
  require(ggplot2)
  my.cols <- rainbow(length(ds))
  my.names <- as.character(nc)
  names(my.cols) <- my.names

  my.list <- list()
  for (i in 1:6){
    for (ii in 1:length(id2)){
      p <- ggplot(NULL, aes_(x = as.name(names(ds[[ii]][4]))))
      p <- p + geom_line(data = ds[[ii]], 
                         aes_(y = as.name(names(ds[[ii]][i])), 
                              colour = as.character(nc[[ii]])))
    }
    p <- p  + scale_colour_manual("Node",
                          breaks = as.character(nc),
                          values = my.cols)
    my.list[[i-dr[1]+1]] <- p
  }
  return(my.list)
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to understand the difference between <- and <<- in practice". I would say that in practice -- don't use `<<-` at all.

Comment: This is really curious. I don't think you should be using `<<-`, but it is very weird that you get that error. `id2` should definitely be available. Not sure how to figure this out without seeing more code. Anything weird you are doing in `data.sift` or `evol.tiles`?

Comment: It might be due to `ggplot`s dealing with variables/environments. You could try if the problem is resolved with installing the latest ggplot version.

Comment: This question may have been closed too quickly. I agree with @Axeman that it is not evident why `id2` goes out of scope here.

Comment: I'd say this should be reopened, but we would probably need to have a look at your functions and some example data to reproduce the error.

Comment: Where do the `prompt1()` and `prompt2()` functions come from? Without having the details, it is hard to judge where your problem comes from.

Comment: Another possibility is that `data.sift` never actually uses the `nc` argument, in which case it isn't evaluated and no error is given..

Comment: Please update your question with all necessary info, so we can have a better look at what the problem might be. Now it is just a guessing game. [See also the info on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: This is one of those cases where the question in the title is a clear duplicate (and arguably, should be closed as such) but the body of the question involves something which isn't a duplicate. I am willing to vote to reopen it, but think that the title should be changed to reflect the actual question (which itself should be expanded to include a [mcve]).

Comment: Try to post the different functions and strip out all the code that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Then give the simplest dataset to reproduce. Right now it's just a guessing game, and the question may be closed again for not being reproducible.

Comment: @Axeman I have the latest version of ggplot. I added the code for `data.sift()' and `evol.tiles()` if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't hurt, but it's still very hard to debug if we can't reproduce on our end.

Comment: @Axeman I'll add a sample data frame in a sec.

Comment: Your `evol.tiles()` function uses a variable (in the inner loop index) that isn't defined anywhere in the code that you show: `id.node`. Where does that come from?

Comment: Again, please remove _everything_ which is not related to your actual issue.

Comment: I am working on it right now. I'll post a minimal working example as soon as I get it to reproduce my error.

Comment: I think I found the issue - as I was trying to generate the working example I discovered that in my function `evol.tiles()` I was calling the `id2` variable instead of `nc` (in the inner loop). @Mikko Marttila: thank you for pointing to that! I guess when I used `<<-` for `prompt2()` I was assigned globally and it could be found when called within `evol.tiles()` but with `<-` it was not available to `evol.tiles()`. Is that what happened?

Comment: I guess I thought that the function would look in the parenting environment for the missing arguments since the `id2` was defined within `fun.exec` the `time.evol()` would be able to find the right value.

Comment: Here is a simple example showing how I would expect the code to behave, even with an incorrectly named variable as it was in my case: if I run function `test <- function(){x*x}`, I get the same error as with my function, i.e., `Error in test() : object 'x' not found`. However, if I run `x<-2` and then `test()`, the output is `[1] 4`. Could someone tell me why wasn't my function behaving in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments, I think I found the issue - while working on a minimal working example I discovered that in my function `evol.tiles()` I was calling the `id2` variable instead of `nc` (in the inner loop). I guess when I used `<<-` for `prompt2()` I was assigned it globally and then it could be found when called from within `evol.tiles()` but with `<-` it was not available to `evol.tiles()`.

Even so, I still don't quite understand why was that happening. I would think that that the function should look in the parenting environment for the missing arguments and since the `id2` was defined within `fun.exec()`, the `time.evol()` should be able to find the right value.

Here is a simple example showing how I would expect the code to behave, even with an incorrectly named variable as it was in my case:

```
test <- function(){x*x}
test()
Error in test() : object 'x' not found
```

If I run the `test()` function on its own, I get the same error as with my function, whic is what I would expect. However, if I assign value to `x`, i.e.,

```
x <- 2
test()
[1] 4
```

the function works just fine. Could someone tell me why wasn't my function behaving in the same way?

**UPDATE:** 
@Aaron: The example you gave, i.e., `rm(x); test2 <- function() { x <- 2; test() }; test2()`, executes for me just fine:

[image]

So I still don't understand what the issue is. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Justyna, I think it's probably best at this point to close this question and open a new one, this one has a lot of baggage that you've discovered isn't important to the question at hand. If you choose to do that, there's one more piece of a MCVE I think you'd need; namely, that inside another function, `test` doesn't do what you expect after assigning `x`, like this: `rm(x); test2 <- function() { x <- 2; test() }; test2()`

Comment: Actually, I think that question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18338331/210673; though the answer there is fairly technical. Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/44427752/210673; that question isn't as similar, but the answer I think might be a better fit. In particular, it's looking in the enclosing environment, not the parent environment.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for the references. Both posts and the references within are really helpful! I don't think I need to post a new question about it. Thank you again!