# Is using assign() to deal with a scoping problem a problem?

Tags: r, scope, assign

When contained inside a custom function, `RVAideMemoire::Anova.clm`
does not find the 'df1' data object that was passed to `ordinal::clm` (It would seem
because it searches for 'df1' in the global environment):

```
library(ordinal)
library(RVAideMemoire)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = factor(sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE)), 
                 y = factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE), ordered=TRUE))

clm_function <- function(dv, gv, df1){
  model <- ordinal::clm(as.formula(paste0(dv, " ~ ", gv)), data = df1)
  result <- RVAideMemoire::Anova.clm(model, type = "II") 
  return(result)
}

clm_function(dv = "y", gv = "x", df1 = df)
```

> Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'df1' not found

One can sidestep this error by using `assign` to put 'df1' in the global
environment temporarily:

```
clm_function_alt <- function(dv, gv, df1){
  assign("df1", df1, envir=globalenv()) # ASSIGN HERE
  model <- ordinal::clm(as.formula(paste0(dv, " ~ ", gv)), data = df1)
  result <- RVAideMemoire::Anova.clm(model, type = "II") 
  rm(df1, pos = 1) # REMOVE HERE
  return(result)
}

clm_function_alt(dv = "y", gv = "x", df1 = df)
```

LyzandeR’s answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601959/error-object-not-found-in-nested-functions) implies that assigning ‘df1’ to the global environment outside the function is the way to go.

But I am wondering if there something potentially problematic with using `assign` from inside a function, like I have shown?

If so, is there a way to instruct  `RVAideMemoire::Anova.clm` to search for ‘df1’ in the execution environment?