# Argument in VAR() not found when executing in nested function

Tags: r, variables, nested, environment

I am trying to run VAR-models between multiple variables, which is why I wrote a function to prepare the data and execute the `vars::VAR()` function, feeding the result to the `vars::irf()` function to generate an IRF model where I subseqyently extract relevant metrics. This function has an argument `max_lag`, in which I define the maximum number of lags to consider when fitting the model.

Hence I define a function like this:

```
library(vars)
data(EuStockMarkets)
f1 <- function(max_lag = 6){
  
  vars::irf(vars::VAR(EuStockMarkets, lag.max = max_lag))
  
}
```

I then call the function:

```
f1(max_lag = 12)
```

which results in

```
Error in VAR(y = ysampled, lag.max = max_lag) : 
  object 'max_lag' not found
```

Note that neither `f1()` nor assigning a new object `m <- vars::VAR(EuStockMarkets, lag.max = max_lag)` and then providing this as input to the `irf()` function, nor pre-loading the package solve the issue.

This seems to be an issue specific to the `vars`-package, as both

```
f2 <- function(test = "test"){
  
  print(paste(test))
  
}

f2(test = "TEST")
[1] "TEST"
```

and

```
f3 <- function(col = "red"){
  
  ggplot(starwars, aes(x = height, y = mass)) +
    geom_point(color = col)
  
}

f3(col = "blue")
```

[image: Output f3(col = "blue")]

work.

I also moved out of my comfort zone and tried to use `get('max_lag')` with the arguments `parent.frame()`, `environment()`, `parent.env(environment())`, or calling a pre-defined environment (which is also not found), following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28605614/10707723).

**Suggestions both welcome regarding specific fix and general issue - I feel there is something substantial about R environments going on here.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't actually that `VAR()` couldn't find `max_lag`, it's that when you called `irf()` on the `VAR()` object, the value `max_lag` didn't follow along, so it was actually `irf()` that couldn't find `max_lag`.  You can solve this by creating a set of arguments that includes `lag.max=max_lag` and then calling `VAR()` on that with `do.call()`.  Here's an example:

```r
library(vars)
data(EuStockMarkets)
  f1 <- function(max_lag = 6){
  args <- list(y=EuStockMarkets, 
               lag.max=max_lag)
  m <- do.call(vars::VAR, args)
  vars::irf(m)
}
res <- f1()
names(res$irf)
#> [1] "DAX"  "SMI"  "CAC"  "FTSE"

res$irf$DAX
#>            DAX      SMI      CAC     FTSE
#>  [1,] 32.05836 29.44197 19.20616 20.35056
#>  [2,] 31.60745 32.37784 19.13026 21.64319
#>  [3,] 30.63930 32.70562 18.66182 21.25947
#>  [4,] 29.73668 31.81143 17.25273 20.64492
#>  [5,] 28.81030 29.08016 15.49562 19.60930
#>  [6,] 26.72902 26.68544 13.52721 18.63569
#>  [7,] 26.30296 26.08855 13.49620 18.25619
#>  [8,] 25.95382 25.70311 13.40278 17.88850
#>  [9,] 25.74752 25.64168 13.36974 17.49341
#> [10,] 25.72072 25.92978 13.38728 17.23849
#> [11,] 25.67485 26.12543 13.41721 17.01522
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I must admit I still don't fully understand - wouldn't irf() take 'max_lag' from the original function environment? what's the difference with do.call()/args?

Comment: What's happening is that `irf()` calls `.boot()` and inside that function it tries to do `update(VAR, y=ysampled)`, when you specify VAR(y, lag.max=max_lag), R doesn't replace the value `max_lag` with a number, `VAR()` just goes to the parent environment to find it.  The problem is the parent environment for `.boot()` is not the global environment, but the environment created by `irf()`, so `max_lag` isn't there.

Comment: When you make a list of arguments, the list doesn't have a pointer to `max_lag`, it has the actual numerical value in it.  So, when `irf()` calls `.boot()` and `.boot()` uses `update(VAR, ...)`, the numerical value of `lag.max` is already there, not a pointer to an object that cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that nested functions exist in different environments, this is quite interesting!