# How to use `parent.env<-` in R?

Tags: r, closures

If I run the following code in R, R will not be responsive after the last command. Does anybody know what causes the problem and how to set the parent environment of an environment? (BTW, I am aware of the difference between `parent.frame` and `parent.env` [What is the difference between parent.frame() and parent.env() in R; how do they differ in call by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439110/what-is-the-difference-between-parent-frame-and-parent-env-in-r-how-do-they))

```
e1=environment()
e2=environment()
parent.env(e1)=e2
parent.env(e1)
```

Comment: `environment()` by itself is the global environment.  So you are creating e1 and e2 are global environment.  If you check `?parent.env`, some examples are there `e1 <- new.env(parent = baseenv()) ;
     e2 <- new.env(parent = e1)`

Comment: If R becomes unresponsive, I would think that to be bug, so you might post a question on the R-devel mailing list. It's not a segfault but it's certainly undesirable. Perhaps you meant to use `new.env()` instead of `environment()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

```
e1 <- new.env()
e2 <- new.env()
parent.env(e1 <- e2
parent.env(e1)
#<environment: 0x10dfaba70>
```