# Variable scope or parent environment

Tags: r, scope

Consider the function with functions below:

```
f1=function(){
 f3=function() print(a)
 f2=function() {
   print(a)
   a=3
   f3()}
 print(a)
 a=2
 f2()

a=1
f1()
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 2
```

Why does `f2()` consider `f1()` its parent environment but `f3()` does not consider `f2()` its parent environment? I expect `f3()` printing `3`, set on `f2()`, rather than `2`.
If a variable is defined inside `f2()`, `f3()` can not find it:

```
f1=function(){
 f3=function() print(b)
 f2=function() {
   print(a)
   b=3
   f3()}
 print(a)
 a=2
 f2()

a=1
f1()
[1] 1
[1] 2
Error in print(b) : object 'b' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `f2()` consider `f1()` its parent environment

Because it is defined inside `f1`.

> but `f3()` does not consider `f2()` its parent environment?

Because it is not defined inside `f2`.

You need to distinguish between containing *environment*, and parent *frame*. `f2` is the *parent frame* of `f3` in your call. But `f1` is its containing environment regardless.

See also [What is the difference between `parent.frame()` and `parent.env()` in R; how do they differ in call by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7439110/1968), and [Hadley’s introduction into environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Comment: Tks, @Konrad. Is there a way to call `f3()` setting `f2()` as its parent.environment?

Comment: I tried to specify the frame as the enviroment without sucess.

Comment: @xm1 Not really, no. You can write `environment(f3) = environment()` inside `f2`. However, this will create *a new copy* of `f3` inside `f2`. For more details it would be helpful to know what you *actually* want to accomplish.

Comment: as said in Hadley´s site, R does not have dynamic scoping. Tks again. I solved just doing the right thing: passing parameters. :)